# Limit of norm of bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $Y$ be complete. Then we have the notion of norm a bounded operator and also the fact that $B(X,Y)$ is complete.

In general, thanks to the triangle inequality, we have that the norm function is continuous, i.e. if $x \rightarrow y$ then $||x|| \rightarrow ||y||$.

This means that if we have a Cauchy sequence of bounded operators $\{T_n\}$, then it is true that, by the completeness of $B(X,Y)$, $T_n \rightarrow T$ and so that $||T_n|| \rightarrow ||T||$. 
Now let's reverse the process: given $||T_n|| \rightarrow c \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\{T_n\}$ is a sequence of bounded operators, one could ask if this implies the existence of a bounded operator such that $T_n \rightarrow T$.

I think that the answer is no, but I cannot think of an example. So my question is: Can anyone provide a counterexample of a non converging sequence of bounded operators such that the sequence of norms converges?

Comment: This isn't true for whatever norm on whatever space.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true even in dimension $1$.
Consider, for example, the linear operators $T_n \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$T_n x := (-1)^n x$.